# When I use Matlab Ros toolbox, turtlebot3 tutorial simulation will not work

Tags: ros, matlab, simulation, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is so strange that I use  [link text](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/simulation/#simulation), the fake node works. However, when I use Matlab Ros toolbox, and input some command like "rosinit", the tutorial doesn't work. It shows that [image: image description]

```
roslaunch turtlebot3_fake turtlebot3_fake.launch
... logging to /home/ise-admin/.ros/log/292cbdaa-2ea7-11e8-9362-509a4c311940/roslaunch-ise-linux-1-5245.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

xacro: Traditional processing is deprecated. Switch to --inorder processing!
To check for compatibility of your document, use option --check-order.
For more infos, see http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Processing_Order
No such file or directory: /home/ise-admin/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3/turtlebot3_description/urdf/turtlebot3_.urdf.xacro
XacroException('No such file or directory: /home/ise-admin/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3/turtlebot3_description/urdf/turtlebot3_.urdf.xacro',)
while processing /home/ise-admin/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3/turtlebot3_bringup/launch/includes/description.launch.xml:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/xacro/xacro '/home/ise-admin/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3/turtlebot3_description/urdf/turtlebot3_.urdf.xacro'] returned with code [2]. 

Param xml is <param command="$(arg urdf_file)" name="robot_description"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I have tried to check the turtlebot3_fake.launch, but it is same to github. I also tried rename a .xarco file as turtlebot3_.urdf.xacro, I copied the code from \ turtlebot3_burger.urdf.xacro to turtlebot3_.urdf.xacro. However, error occurs.[image: image description]

I want to know why the tutorial does work.Is there any relationship between the "strike" and "Matlab Ros toolbox"?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286300/when-i-use-matlab-ros-toolbox,-turtlebot3-tutorial-simulation-will-not-work./) by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2018-03-23

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on 2018-03-23**:
[link text](http://file:///home/ise-admin/Screenshot%20from%202018-03-23%2001-11-58.png)

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-23**:
Please don't use an image to display text. Images are not searchable and people cannot copy and paste the text from the image. Please update your question with a copy and paste of the text using the *preformatted text* (`101010`) button instead of using an image.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-23**:
http://wiki.ros.org/Support

**Comment by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on 2018-03-23**:
Ok, I have added text for first picture, as for the second one, I just want to show that my method was not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello :)

You have to set which TurtleBot3 you want.

```
$ export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL = burger
```

or

```
$ export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL = waffle_pi
```

and

```
$ roslaunch turtlebot3_fake turtlebot3_fake.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) with karma: 811 on 2018-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pujie](https://answers.ros.org/users/34177/pujie/) on 2018-03-23**:
Yes, this is parts of the problem. I solved it today. In recent days turtlebot3 has updated their code on github. So I update the code by git pull and export the variable(maybe change them in bashrc is good too)  export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger
export TB3_MODEL=burger
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should be

```
$ export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger
```

or

```
$ export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=waffle_pi
```

and then

```
$ roslaunch turtlebot3_fake turtlebot3_fake.launch
```

NOTE: the = sign shouldn't have space between words

---

Originally posted by [AustinJia](https://answers.ros.org/users/36585/austinjia/) with karma: 31 on 2018-07-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2018-07-22**:
Minor details like that should be rather posted as a comment on the first answer and not posted as a separate answer.